# ruby Class.new(arg).method equivalent to Class.method(arg)

Tags: ruby

I have a class that includes a method to return a calculation based on the instance of the class.

```
class Foo
  def initialize(arg)
    @arg = arg
  end

  def baz
    @arg.dosomething
  end
end
```

Is it possible to reformat this such that calling `Foo.new(bar).baz` is equal to `Foo.baz(bar)`?

Comment: Sure `def self.baz(bar); bar.dosomething; end` or `def self.baz(bar); self.new(bar).baz; end` is probably better as it re uses the same method.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem. What's the actual problem that this approach is intended to solve? Context matters.

Comment: @CodeGnome it's just an exercise in scoring Scrabble plays but the exercise prompt calls for it to return a score if called as `Scrabble.new(word).score` or as `Scrabble.score(word)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to reformat this such that calling either `Foo.new(bar).baz` is equal to `Foo.baz(bar)`?

There are two different ways you can accomplish this. One looks like this:

```
def baz
  self.class.baz(@arg)
end

def self.baz(arg)
  arg.dosomething
end
```

This makes sense when the calculation doesn't depend on any other instance methods or attributes. See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/I8m6/1

Alternatively, you can make the class method create an instance by calling `new` and call the instance method:

```
def self.baz(arg)
  new(arg).baz
end
```

However, I think this is usually an antipattern: You're creating an instance just to call one method and then throw it away. I don't recommend this, but nevertheless you can see it on repl.it: https://repl.it/I8m6

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I need to be able to call both `Class.new(arg).method` as well as `Class.method(arg)`.  It looks like I just have to define `self.method(arg)` in addition to defining `method`.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson Follow the repl.it link(s) to see it in action. It works exactly as you describe. (P.S. I swapped the order of the solutions in my answer, so the "better" one is at the top.)

Comment: Yes, I did that.  Works perfectly.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson Glad to help. If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

### Call Class Method from Instance Method

> [I]t's just an exercise in scoring Scrabble plays but the exercise prompt calls for it to return a score if called as Scrabble.new(word).score or as Scrabble.score(word).

The key to your X/Y problem is in your own [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395713/ruby-class-newarg-method-equivalent-to-class-methodarg?noredirect=1#comment75791789_44395713), quoted above. The easiest solution is to ensure the instance method always calls the class method. For example:

```
class Scrabble
  def initialize word=nil
    @word = word
  end

  def score
    self.class.score @word
  end

  def self.score word
    "Class method: #{word.inspect}"
  end
end

Scrabble.new('foo').score
#=> "Class method: foo"

Scrabble.score('foo')
#=> "Class method: foo"

Scrabble.new('foo').score == Scrabble.score('foo')
#=> true
```

There may be other ways to get the job done, but this certainly seems like a simple and clear approach that demonstrably works.

Comment: Please explain how this is an XY problem?